# Regression with y > 1 dimension

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working on a project to decode brain activity related to human vision. I present images on a computer screen and record the brain activity using a mobile EEG headset, I then use machine learning to find a connection between particular features of an image and the relevant EEG.

In practice each training sample consists of learning from 500 EEG features to 50 image features which is no problem for the SKLearn Ridge regressor, however I am interested in trying other regressors. When I tried the same code with a LinearSVR I realised that its fit function did not support a y of > 1 dimension. In order to get around this I simply created a list of regressors which each took the EEG and a single image feature as a training sample, then I can get a prediction from each regressor in this list and combine the results into a vector of image features. This does work however it is very slow and awkward, and I am wondering if SKLearn (or Python in general) has a more principled way to implement these cases with y > 1 dimensions. I should mention that I am using Pool from the Multiprocessing module to try to speed things up.

I also find that although much of the core functionality from SKLearn works well, my use case is too different to apply many utility functions. For example (I think) I had to implement my own gridsearch function rather than use the built in one for the reason above. Is this the norm? I don't feel the problem I am trying to solve should be particularly unique.

Comment: Have you considered either [random forest regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) or [random forest classification](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) in sklearn?  These can accomodate endogenous variables with >1 dimensions.  When you go to use `.fit`, you can specify y as having [n_samples, n_outputs].

Comment: In addition to estimators suggested above have a look at [MultiOutput Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multioutput-regression)

Comment: Also, this question is more suited for stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Random Forests are indeed on my list of TODOs, but I was looking for some way to solve the same problem for any other regressors I wanted to try. MultiOutput Regression sounds spot on, I'll give it a shot thanks. RE stats, is there a way to migrate the question or is your comment for future reference?